# About Chords in python

Tags: python

Below is my code from assignment 4, which is doing simple chord transpositions. Now, we need to modify it according to the following instruction.

> Modify your program from assignment 4. Currently your chords consist
>   only of the root. However, following the root there may be additional
>   characters. For example, we could have a D chord or D7, Dm, Dm7,
>   Dsus2, Dmaj7, and many others. the characters after the root (in this
>   case D) describe different variations on the chord.
>
> Edit your function that makes the string of chords into a list of
>   chords: After you make the list (of strings), make a list of tuples.
>   Each of the tuples will consist of two parts: the root of the chord
>   and the variation of the chord. For example, "D" becomes ("D", ""),
>   "Dsus2" becomes ("D", "sus2"), "F#" becomes ("F#", ""), "F#m" becomes
>   ("F#", "m") Notice that the root is either one or two characters. The
>   variation of the chord is zero or more characters.
>
> Edit your function that transposes: When you iterate over the list of
>   chord tuples, transpose only the root of the chord. The rest of the
>   chord (its variation) is not affected. For example, if transposing +3
>   half-steps, ("F#", "m") would result in the chord "Am" and ("C", "")
>   would result in the chord "D#".
>
> If the original string in the main function is "Eb F7 Bb7 Eb Gm Ab Gm
>   Fm Eb" and we transpose -1 half steps, the final result is "D E7 A7 D
>   Gbm G Gbm Em D"

Here is my program from assignment 4. I have no idea what to do next.

```
def main():

    chords = 'Eb D C F A# G'

    halfsteps = int(input('how many half steps? ')
    print(transpose(chords, halfsteps))

def makeChordList(s):
    return s.split()

def transpose(chrdstr, halfsteps):
    if 'b' in chrdstr:
        scale = "S Bb B C Sb S Eb E F Gb G Ab".split()  
    else:
        scale = "A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#".split() 

    chrdlst = makeChordList(chrdstr)
    tchords = [] # Turns it into a list

    for c in chrdlst:
        i = (scale.index(c) = halfsteps) % 12 # find "c" from scale. Using divide  by 12 will bring it back to since
        #
        tchords.append(scale[i])

    return ' '.join(tchords)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you need help understanding the assignment? I don't think it can be any clearer than this. If previously you divided "E F# G" into a list ["E", "F#", "G"] and then transposed each member of the list, you now need to divide "E F#7 Gm" into a list of tuples [("E", ""), ("F#", "7"), ("G", "m")] and then apply the same transpose function to the first element in each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly messy function to convert your chord list into a list of tuples:

```
def makeTuples(listIn):
    rootList = []
    variationList = []
    for i in range(len(listIn)):
        tempLen = len(listIn[i])

        if tempLen == 1:
            rootList.append(listIn[i])
            variationList.append("")

        else:
            if listIn[i][1] == "#" or listIn[i][1] == "b":
                rootList.append(listIn[i][0:2])
                if tempLen > 2:
                    variationList.append(listIn[i][2:])
                else:
                    variationList.append("")
            else:
                rootList.append(listIn[i][0])
                variationList.append(listIn[i][1:])

    return list(zip(rootList,variation))
```

As for the transposing:

```
def transpose(tupleList, halfSteps, sharps):
    returnList = []
    if sharps:
        scale = "A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#".split() 
    else:
        scale = "A Bb B C Db D Eb E F Gb G Ab".split()  

    for i in range(len(tupleList)):
        thisRoot = tupleList[i][0]
        firstPos = scale.index(thisRoot) # Consider adding some error-handling here
        newPos = (firstPos + halfSteps) % 12
        returnList.append((scale[newPos], tupleList[i][1]))

    return returnList
```

Implemented, your `main()` could look something like this:

```
def main():
    chords = input("Enter chords, separated by spaces: ")
    halfSteps = int(input("Enter number of steps: "))
    myChords = getList(chords)
    myTuples = makeTuples(myChords)
    result = transpose(myTuples, halfSteps, True) # True for Sharps, False for Flats
```

Comment: Oh dear lord. Please.. **Never.... _EVER_ use** `input()` **inside of** `eval()`. That's bad mojo. A user could put anything in that input and it would run as valid python code. All it would take is a user typing `import os; os.system("rm -rf /")` and there goes your whole system.

Comment: a simple `halfSteps = int(input("Enter the number of steps:"))` will do for integer conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jebby! I'm fairly new to this.